# Python TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> when trying to do math on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'XYF':             TimeUS           GyrX           GyrY           GyrZ         AccX  \
0        207146570    0.000832914    0.001351716  -0.0004189798    -0.651183   
1        207186671    0.001962787    0.001242457  -0.0001859666   -0.6423497   
2        207226791   9.520243E-05    0.001076498  -0.0005664826   -0.6360412   
3        207246474   0.0001093059    0.001616917   0.0003615251   -0.6342875   
4        207286244    0.001412051   0.0007565815  -0.0003780428    -0.637755   


[103556 rows x 12 columns], 'DAR':           TimeUS RSSI RemRSSI TxBuf Noise RemNoise RxErrors Fixed
0      208046965  159     161    79    25       29        0     0
1      208047074  159     161    79    25       29        0     0
2      208927455  159     159    91    28       28        0     0
3      208927557  159     159    91    28       28        0     0


[4136 rows x 8 columns], 'NK2':            TimeUS    IVN    IVE   IVD    IPN   IPE    IPD IMX  IMY IMZ  IYAW  \
0       207147350  -0.02   0.02  0.00  -0.02  0.01   0.20   0    0   0  1.94   
1       207187259  -0.02   0.02  0.00  -0.02  0.01   0.20   0    0   0  1.94   
2       207227559  -0.02   0.02  0.00  -0.02  0.01   0.14   0    0   0  1.77   
3       207308304   0.02   0.02  0.00  -0.01  0.01  -0.05   0    0   0  1.77   
4       207347766   0.02   0.02  0.00  -0.01  0.01  -0.05   0    0   0  0.82
```

I first separated the column I want to do math with:

```
new_time = dfs['XYF']['TimeUS']
```

Then I have tried several things to do some math on it but I had no luck.
First I just treated it like a list. so

```
new_time_F = new_time / 1000000
```

That didn't work, gave me a float error of:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

so I did this:

```
new_time_F = float (new_time) / 1000000
```

This give me an error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have a dict with a list of dfs as the values and the names of the dfs as the keys? This is what it's showing and not a df.

Comment: @EdChum Yes, sorry didn't know there was a big different between df and dfs.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What if you do this (as was suggested earlier):

```
new_time = dfs['XYF']['TimeUS'].astype(float)
new_time_F = new_time / 1000000
```

Comment: Yes that worked, however, why can't I do this dfs['XYF'].astype(float)? why can't I convert the entire thing to float? it gives me an error of TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Indeed you can not apply `astype` to dataframes. Use `applymap` instead. e.g. `dfs['XYF'] = dfs['XYF'].applymap(float)`

Comment: ah! applymap that worked! Is this because astype only works with a list? or how does applymap ignores any strings in my dataframe?

Comment: The `astype` method applies to `Series` pandas objects (i.e. dataframe columns). `applymap` applies a function to all elements of the dataframe

Comment: Then shouldn't have it worked if I just did dfs.applymap(float)? because it doesn't work.

Comment: As others have mentioned, your variable named `dfs` is a dictionary that __contains__ dataframes. You cannot apply the function to a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Seems your initial data contains strings and not numbers. It would probably be best to ensure that the data is already of the required type up front.

However, you can convert strings to numbers like this:

```
pd.Series(['123', '42']).astype(float)
```

instead of `float(series)`

Comment: That didn't work. I have tried this: pd.Series(new_time_F).astype(float) but I got an error TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Answer (score -1):

You can use from the `pd.to_numeric(s)`

Comment: If you want this answer to be helpful you should add some more explanation why it solves the problem, and an example.

Comment: make sure to add coerce.  to_numeric is equivalent to astype(float)