# Make datetime.date column in python from other year,month and day column

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to make a datetime.date type column by combining the year,month and day columns.

This is what i've tried.

```
        df['date']= date(df['year'],df['month'],df['day'])
```

It's giving me an error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I tried parsing by using int() but its giving me the same error.

Comment: Please show a sample of your df along with expected output. Passing a series into `date` is not going to work.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000428/python-typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-int-when-trying-to-do-m

Comment: How can i parse a string "2001-12-2" into a datetime64[nt] format by year,month,day? That would also solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a string date-time, then use to_datetime to get the series you want.
Think x[1] as month, x[0] as day, and x[2] as year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,2000],[2,3,2003]])
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x: f"{x[1]}-{x[0]}-{x[2]}", axis=1))
```